# Does Marine Le Pen oppose circumcision?

Tags: religion, france, marine-le-pen, male-circumcision

In [Marine Le Pen's Insane Kippah Ban Defense](http://www.tabletmag.com/scroll/112808/marine-le-pens-insane-kippah-ban-defense) it's stated that Marine Le Pen is opposed to (male) circumcision:

> This becomes most apparent in Le Pen’s views on the headscarf and the
>   yarmulke: While some of her rivals would outlaw these in public
>   schools, Le Pen wants to ban them in all public places. In conjunction
>   with her opposition to ritual slaughter and male circumcision, this
>   would have a much more extreme outcome for religious freedom than
>   anything the mainstream right has ever suggested. In effect, her
>   policies would make it impossible for many French Jews and Muslims to
>   carry out what they perceive as their basic religious duties.

However, I haven't found any mention of that in the English-language Wikipedia article on her [political positions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_positions_of_Marine_Le_Pen) or in the French-language Wikipedia article about [her](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marine_Le_Pen). Googling has been unsuccessful, even when using "circoncision marine le pen", as has searching English-language Google News.

Is Marine Le Pen opposed to circumcision?

Comment: @Bregalad a newspaper report saying that she said X on Y date would be equally suitable.

Comment: A found some like articles this one (http://jssnews.com/2017/04/26/neinjude/ ), but I don't know how realiable they are at all. I would like an actual footage of her or a reliable source.

Comment: While it's a valid question, it should include the fact that opposition to the practice isn't a Le Pen right wing special. Most French left wing opposes that as well, especially radical ones.

Comment: @user4012: though a large part of French left wing is anti-religion *as a personal belief*, very few actually propose a ban on religious signs in the public space and let people decide of their own.

Comment: @Taladris - I'll need to dig up data on France specifically, but EU-wide ant-circumcision efforts were led by decidedly left wing (SPD) Marlene Rupprecht from Germany

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can't read her mind, so I'm basing this answer on [the political program published on her website](https://www.marine2017.fr/programme/visuels/). You might argue that she may include points in her program that she does not actually wish to implement, or on the other side hide things she wants to implement, in order to gain popularity, and you'll probably be right. The same could be said with any politician during an electoral campaign.

Her priorities are presented in her "144 engagements pour la France" which is presented in a 24 page flyer available in PDF format.

- Circumcision is not mentioned anywhere.
- Jews or Judaism aren't mentioned either
- Islam is mentioned in points 9, 29 and 32:

> 9. Défendre les droits des femmes : lutter contre l’islamisme qui fait reculer leurs libertés fondamentales [...]

> 29. Interdire et dissoudre les organismes de toute nature liés aux ondamentalistes islamistes. Expulser tous les étrangers en lien avec le fondamentalisme islamiste.

> 32. Rétablir l’indignité nationale pour les individus coupables de crimes et élits liés au terrorisme islamiste.

This roughly translates as

> 9. Defend women's right : Battle against Islamism which violates [women's] fundamental rights [...]

> 29. Forbid and dissolve groups linked with fundamental Islamist. Expel foreigners related with fundamental Islamism.

> 32. Restore national shame for people guilty of crimes and linked with Islamist terrorism.

Point 9 means she is definitely against female circumcision (also called excision). She says noting about male circumcision, it's extremely unlikely she support it, but I'd say she looks neutral about it. **Fighting circumcision does not seem to be a priority for her.**

Note that her website has a platform allowing to ask questions, although I don't know the details of how it works, but theoretically it'd be possible to ask the question directly there (and have a 0.01% of chance of it being answered).

Comment: What direction are you assuming in your  correlation between male circumcision and Judaism? Don't sects of all the Abrahamic religions practise it?

Comment: @origimbo Correlation is always both ways - you might be thinking of *causation*.  Both Judaism and Islam are major causes of circumcision;  Christianity really isn't.